# History of "have", "avoir", "haben", etc. as auxiliary

Tags: historical-linguistics, germanic-languages, romance-languages, perfect, standard-average-european

In Geoff Pullum's recent post [Being an Auxiliary](http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2016/07/07/being-an-auxiliary/) on the Lingua Franca blog, he states that the sense of "have" as an auxiliary (forming the perfect tense) evolved from the possession sense, "but the speciation that separated them took place half a millennium ago".

This struck me as much too recent, given that an almost identical perfect construction exists not only in most (all?) other Germanic languages, but also in the Romance languages (with the exception of Portuguese?). But, sure enough, the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/84705) says that this evolution "to some extent parallels developments in other Germanic and Romance languages, but appears at least partly to reflect development within English". (On the other hand, it also says "This development appears to have largely taken place before the written record.")

Assuming that it indeed happened within the last half millennium or so, how can this kind of fundamental language change occur in parallel between a dozen or so languages dispersed over a continent (from Iceland to Romania)? Did the innovation occur in one region and then spread between languages (like a new vocabulary item might), or is it better to think of it as a natural development that came about independently in multiple language communities (like simplification of noun inflection)?

Comment: I think that what Prof. Pullum is saying is not that the perfect arose half a millenium ago but that the modern strict distinction between English auxiliaries and lexicals arose half a millennium ago. And I think it's true that many of the characteristic *NICE* properties which distinguish auxiliaries from lexicals are products of the transition from ME to ModE.

Comment: See also this question and its answers: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17462/do-germanic-words-have-romance-qualities-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Areal features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areal_feature)** develop when languages from different groups or branches are in contact with each other.  There are a few main mechanisms - common substrate, common superstrate, parallel development.

About the feature in question:

The use of *have*, *haben*, *avoir*, *avere* etc as an auxiliary for the past tense is an example of an areal feature.  The areas where languages use this auxiliary correspond roughly to former Celtic-speaking areas and to those where language was heavily influenced by Vulgar Latin, including [deep in the Balkans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balkan_sprachbund#Analytic_perfect_tense).  I will not speculate on the ultimate source and exact mechanism here.

Danish, Dutch, French, German and Italian represent a transitional zone, where *to be* is the auxiliary for a specific subgroup of verbs (primarily verbs that indicate motion or change of state when used intransitively – in French and Italian also all reflexive verbs, and in Italian also unaccusative verbs in general), and *to have* for all others.  Old Spanish and Middle English had this distinction too, which is to say this feature's area was still evolving in recent centuries - across language families.

It is not common unbroken Indo-European legacy - Latin *habere* and Germanic *haben* are not actually cognates, and classical Latin and Greek made little use of auxiliaries anyway.  Many Indo-European languages outside of Western Europe - Armenian, Iranian languages, Slavic languages beside Macedonian - use the copula as an auxiliary, but most do not use any translation or cognate of *habere* or *haben* as an auxiliary for the past tense.

[image]

[Pardon the seeming equation of languages with current political entities]

Comment: The use of the verb "to be" as an auxiliary to form transitive and intransitive verbs is wide-spread in Iranian and Indo-Aryan languages. Also in Aramaic (Semitic).

Comment: Yes, but the delicate balance as in French, Italian, German and Dutch is not.

Comment: Re-worded to be hopefully more clear

Comment: Standard Ukrainian has future tense with "to have", the map does not reflect this.

Comment: @ConstantineGeist The map is for the past tense.  English has auxiliary *be* and even *do* for some random tenses, the map is not intended to show that either.

Comment: "... but most do not use any translation or cognate of habere or haben." That's a tall claim without a solid etymology of both words, the ga-prefix, or even the auxiliary usage that is in question. Oddly enough, *\*kap- / \*keh₂p-* is suspect of a supstrate, and the pedigree of *\*gʰeh₁bʰ- or \*ǵʰeh₁bʰ* isn't impeccable either. But it isn't #badlinguistics if it's CO. It's just linguistics being bad.

Comment: It is worth to notice that this map is not very accurate by painting Portuguese as green. To express past perfect, Portuguese uses only its conjugation, no auxiliary. If you happen to use "ter" + participle you will make a different tense that does not correspond to other Romance Languages!

Comment: @ErgativeMan Historically Portuguese even had *haver*, the point of the map is that when an auxiliary is used for the past, it is from a verb that means *to have*, not *to be*, even for verbs of motion or state.

Comment: I'd be interested where the line is, is Occitan like Iberian Romance in this regard?

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer, yes, I know that. What I am saying is that Portuguese does not do that like the other ones.

Comment: @ErgativeMan There are differences within Germanic and Slavic too, even within variants or registers of one language.

Comment: Yes, there are, the map is just not very accurate

Comment: @ErgativeMan The fact that the exact form created by _ter_ + past participle has a different nuance in Portuguese does not change the fact that Portuguese can use a verb meaning ‘to have’, but not one meaning ‘to be’, to create active verb forms whose meaning is past-based (as opposed to present- or future-based), which is what the map shows. As such, dark green is the correct colour for Portugal.

Comment: What _is_ inaccurate on the map is colouring Ireland blue, because Irish does _not_ use a verb meaning ‘to be’ to form past-based forms – like the other light green areas, it uses a verb meaning ‘to be’ to form past-based forms (the perfective aspect) of certain verbs of motion, and a construction meaning ‘to have’ for other verbs. The complication is that Irish has no verb meaning ‘to have’, and the construction used contains the verb meaning ‘to be’ (I have X = X is at me).

Comment: And just for accuracy: the light-green areas do not generally (or at all?) use _be_ for intransitives and _have_ for transitives. The exact rules differ (e.g., only French uses _be_ for all reflexive verbs, as far as I know), but the distinction most have in common is between verbs of motion (or change of state) vs everything else. It is true that when normally intransitive verbs that use _be_ are used transitively, they usually switch to _have_, but transitive verbs as a general category use _have_ in the light-green areas.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don’t have a strong feeling on motion/state vs. intransitive, but is there really no motion happening in “Er hat Auto gefahren.” (vs “Er ist gefahren.”)?

Comment: @Adam Yes, there’s motion there – that’s why _fahren_ normally uses _be_. I may have been a little unclear, but the base rule is that _be_ is only for verbs that describe motion or change of state and are used intransitively – everything else uses _have_ (including, usually motion or state verbs used transitively). So you don’t say, “*Er ist geschlafen” or “*Er ist gelacht” even though those are transitive.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet True.  Feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Brief edit added!

Answer (score 0):

Portuguese has an original pluperfect from Latin and a compound pluperfect tense, e.g. partíramos / tinhamos partido = we had left. The simple pluperfect is gradually becoming a literary form. 'ter' is the usual auxiliary, but 'haver' is also found.